# Mongoengine flask get dbstats

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

Cannot figure out how to get db.stats in Mongoengine.
I've tried:

```
db = MongoEngine()
db.stats()
```

Also

```
db.Document.objects.stats()
db.Document.stats()
```

Also tried to execute JS, but nothing works and documentation is very poor.

Answer (score 1):

`db.stats` it is a [mongo's shell method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.stats/#db.stats)

You can try something like that:

```py
from mongoengine.connection import get_connection
con = get_connection()

con.get_database().eval('db.stats()')
con.get_database().eval('db.getCollectionInfos()')
```

Also I advise you to examine objects with dir method, sometimes it could be useful:

```py
from pprint import pprint
pprint(dir(con))
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoEngine is a wrapper for PyMongo. So to get the stats of a mongo database using mongoengine you could run the 'dbstats' mongodb api command on the database, using the pymongo command funtion like this:

```
from mongoengine import connect

client = connect()
db = client.get_database('your_database_name')
db_stats = db.command('dbstat')
coll_stats = db.command('collstats', 'your_colletion_name')
print(db_stats)
print(coll_stats)
```